# Not able to run a simple JSP program in Eclipse with Tomcat server 7 in browser

Tags: eclipse, http, jsp, http-status-code-404, tomcat7

I have written the following code in Eclipse, and store this file in this location: `tomcat/webapps/jsp/sample.jsp.`

I have also included the Sub directories WEB-INF and classes and lib in this jsp folder.

And I have given this url in the google chrome browser first time and next time in Internet Explorer both shows the  404 error with description:

> The requested resource(/jsp/sample.jsp) is not available**.

My code is:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.io.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    hello
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you sir, here are the steps;
1. Tomcat is installed in c:\Program files\Apache\tomcat 7.0\

1. I am using Eclipse helio zip file and extracted that in c:\eclipse...
2. Then I have followed the steps from "http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html" to set up server in eclipse.

4.Then I start the jsp file from "file->new->other->wizard->web->jsp  file. Then I open the jsp file in the eclipse editor.

1. After that I start the [tomcat7.0 server at localhost]
2. I save the file and copy the jsp file from the eclipse workspace and paste it in the webapps folder.

these were the steps I have followed.

can you help me sir.

Comment: Why did you manually put the file in Tomcat's deploy folder instead of letting Eclipse do it automatically if you're already using Eclipse? This suggests that you're actually not starting/running the Tomcat instance you think you're using. If you describe the steps how you deploy and start in detail, we may be able to point out the exact mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem.

1. First I uninstalled both Eclipse and tomcat 7 and Reinstalled it.
2. I followed the instruction in the http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html
3. Then I copy and paste the Root folder from Tomcat (c:\tomcat\webapps\ROOT) and paste it in the eclipse (c:\users\workspace\ .metadata\ .plugins\ org.eclipse.wst.server.core\ tmp0\ wtpwebapps\ ROOT)
   here we want to right click in this eclipse ROOT folder and paste it.
4. Then follow the usual procedure to run the eclipse program. Each time I restarted the server and it now works fine.